# Pointing wsdl file from pom.xml in webapp

Tags: maven, wsdl, pom.xml

I want to refer to a WSDL file from my POM file of Maven Webapp.
It is situated at ..WebApp\src\main\webapp\WSDL\NewWebService.wsdl.

WSDL/NewWebService.wsdl

This gives me error, please suggest.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it mean? `refer to a WSDL file`. Refer from the some plugin?

Comment: Yes, I want it for plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer path, using maven property `${basedir}`.

```
<wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WSDL/NewWebService.wsdl</wsdl>
```

or

```
<file>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WSDL/NewWebService.wsdl</file>
```

or something else. (You didn't say anything about used maven-plugin)